# Animate curve point by point

Tags: python, animation, bezier-curves, keyframes, geometry

I am loading the data of a line from a csv file to create a curve. If I animate the curve by keyframing the "factor end" property in the UI, I get the visual animation I want, but the mapping doesn't work, since my path is traversed with a (known - I can generate that csv data, if needed) different speed. However, in the csv data, each point is 1/50 s after the next, and I want to "extend"/animate the curve using this information.

**1st**
I've tried the UI with all 3 "end factor mappings", but none let me specify more in detail.
Since the points are a constant time-duration apart, I would just need a "show 1 point per frame" option, but this didn't work for the 3 mappings, that I can choose from the menu. Only start and end points are synchronized to my other motion, of which I know it's correct. Maybe the problem is with my path settings? -> see below in the script, how I generate/set the path.

**2nd**
Another idea is to keyframe when loading the data in python directly.
I've tried modifying my loading/curve generation script:

```
import bpy # blender python API
import csv

# create the Curve Datablock
curveData = bpy.data.curves.new('myCurve', type='CURVE')
curveData.dimensions = '3D'
curveData.resolution_u = 1

curveData.bevel_depth = 0.002 # m thickness of the path in m
curveData.bevel_resolution = 10
curveData.use_fill_caps = True # the rounded line should not be hollow

# map coords to spline
polyline = curveData.splines.new('POLY')
polyline.use_endpoint_u = True

curveOB = bpy.data.objects.new('myCurve', curveData)

bpy.context.collection.objects.link(curveOB)

#with open('/home/mike/Documents/ownCloud/3D/blender/data/p_err_2.csv') as csvfile:
with open('/home/mike/Documents/ownCloud/3D/blender/data/p_ref.csv') as csvfile:
    readcsv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    k = 0
    for i, row in enumerate(readcsv):
      if (i % 1) == 0:
        if k != 0:
            polyline.points.add(1)
        polyline.points[k].co = (float(row[0]), float(row[1]), float(row[2]), 1)
        k += 1
        polyline.points[0].keyframe_insert('co',frame=k)
```

but the keyframes - if I undestand correctly - just place the points where they already are .. But I wanted them to appear at this keyframe.

Is there a way to change the "end factor" mapping, that reveils points by a constant time difference? Is this something that could be achieved with fcurves? Or is there a way to repair my loading keyframe thing?

**3rd**
I've now also tried to use Geometry nodes and the combination of the

```
Index -> Greater Than -> Delete Geometry (Point)
```

will delete the Verticies of the curve object, rather than the points that defined the curve.
If I use `Spline Parameter` instead of `Index`, either the whole curve is removed with negative values, or it is displayed in full with values greater than zero.

**4th**
I've tried this "hide" property of the points, but it's apparently not used to eliminate the effect of the control point?

```
points = curveOB.data.splines.active.points
# Loop through and hide points up to the specified index
for i, point in enumerate(points):
    if i <= 5:
        point.hide = True
        point.keyframe_insert(data_path="hide", frame=2)
    else:
        point.hide = False
        point.keyframe_insert(data_path="hide", frame=3)

# Update the curve object
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
```

Comment: You could use geonodes to delete every point with index higher than current frame number…

Comment: I've tried to achieve what you suggested and it seems very plausible, but I couldn't get it to work with my experiments -> see last edit of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found a solution using python:

I've added points for all datapoints in the csv file.
First I set the position of all points to the first point. Next, I animate their position, such that all "not shown" points move with the next point to be shown.

```
import bpy # blender python API
import csv

# create the Curve Datablock
curveData = bpy.data.curves.new('myCurve', type='CURVE')
curveData.dimensions = '3D'
curveData.resolution_u = 1

curveData.bevel_depth = 0.002 # m thickness of the path in m
curveData.bevel_resolution = 10
curveData.use_fill_caps = True # the rounded line should not be hollow

# map coords to spline
polyline = curveData.splines.new('POLY')   
curveOB = bpy.data.objects.new('myCurve', curveData)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(curveOB)

data_path = '<file>/data.csv' 
with open(data_path) as csvfile:
    readcsv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    k = 0
    for i, row in enumerate(readcsv):
        if i == 0:
            # save the first value -> all points will be placed there at frame 0
            row0 = row
        if (i % 1) == 0:
            if k != 0:
                # add points for every value in the file
                polyline.points.add(1)
            # initialize all points at the row0 position at frame 0
            polyline.points[k].co = (float(row0[0]), float(row0[1]), float(row0[2]), 1)
            polyline.points[k].keyframe_insert('co', frame=0)
            k += 1
    
    # reset the file and reade from the start
    csvfile.seek(0)
    
    k = 0
    for i, row in enumerate(readcsv):
        if (i % 1) == 0:
            # place all following points at data position at frame k
            for m, point in enumerate(polyline.points):
                if m >= k:
                    point.co = (float(row[0]), float(row[1]), float(row[2]), 1)
                    point.keyframe_insert('co',frame=k)
            k += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your curve beveled, it becomes a mesh and in Geometry Nodes it is considered to be a mesh.

[image]

So you have to remove `bevel_depth` to keep it as curve, and then you can use it as curve in Geometry Nodes:

[image]

When you see the desired effect, you can add beveling after removing control points:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I'm sure this is a valid solution as well! Meanwhile I've managed to achieve what I needed in python, which is a very convenient way for me, since I only need to load the file similar to the other measurements, that I have.